# Delegate function in not invoke properly on delete CollectionView item Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, appdelegate

I have created `PhotoCollectionViewController` which contains all photos fetched from server by using `Alamofire`. Now I want to implement delete function on photos. I have used `tap-gesture` for it. Created custom alert Xib and its successfully showing. Custom alert xib have two button `cancel` and `Delete`. 
On delete button I have create delegate but for some reason its not working even its not invoking properly. Actually I have to pass `AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].projectUnitImageId` which is imageID to delete it from server. Manually without delegation and webservice its working. But Once I have used delegate function not calling.

Issues:

- Need to use delegate or other way so I can delete.
- `AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].projectUnitImageId` have to pass ImageId value to delete Image web service call but How?

Please anyone can guide me.

Xib FotoDeleteAlert & Delegate:

```
protocol handleDeleteAction {
    func didDeleteButtonClicked(_: UIButton)
}

@IBDesignable class FotoDeleteAlert: UIView {

    var delegate: handleDeleteAction?

    @IBOutlet weak var deleteBtn: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didDelete(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func didCancel(_ sender: Any) {
        removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func didDelete(_ sender: Any) {

        self.delegate?.didDeleteButtonClicked(sender as! UIButton)


    }
}
```

PhotoCollectionViewController:

```
let deleteAlertView: FotoDeleteAlert? = nil  // defined on the top

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellName, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell


            if(indexPath.row < (AppData?.imageList?.count ?? 0)){
                cell.imageView.isHidden = false
                cell.closeIcon.isHidden = false
                cell.addIcon.isHidden = true
                let dic = AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].url ?? " "
                cell.imageView.image =  UIImage(url: URL(string: dic))


                let imgId = AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].projectUnitImageId
                cell.closeIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                cell.closeIcon.tag = indexPath.row
                let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeImage(_:)))
                cell.closeIcon.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

            } else {
                cell.imageView.isHidden = true
                cell.closeIcon.isHidden = true
                cell.addIcon.isHidden = false
            }

            return cell
        }

@objc func removeImage(_ sender: AnyObject){

            deleteAlertView?.delegate = self
            let alert = FotoDeleteAlert.loadViewFromNib()
            alert!.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(alert!)

        }


//MARK: - Delegate Function

    extension PhotoCollectionViewController: handleDeleteAction {

        func didDeleteButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
            // below code manual working without delegate and web services work.

            let row = sender.view.tag
            self.data?.remove(at: row.row)
            self.images?.remove(at: row.row)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `deleteAlertView`?

Comment: @vpoltave  I initialize it after class `PhotoCollectionViewController:UIViewController` name and then removeImage func

Answer (score 1):

Relace your removeImage function with followng

```
@objc func removeImage(_ sender: AnyObject){


    let fotoXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FotoDeleteAlert", owner: self,options: nil)
    let alertView = fotoXib?.first as! FotoDeleteAlert
    alertView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(alertView)

}
```

Comment: I have tried  but function is not calling `func didDeleteButtonClicked` on PhotoCollectionView. even I have the breakpoints.

Comment: @IBAction func didDelete(_ sender: Any) {

        self.delegate?.didDeleteButtonClicked(sender as! UIButton)


    }
is this function is being called? try to print something in this function or you can use breakpoint as well.

Comment: I'm afraid if your relation has not being established with your xib file.

Comment: When user tap on collectionView cell it hits `removeImage func` which is working and it shows alert but on alert button `delete` it has to come in `didDeleteButtonClicked` but its not coming here I have set the breakpoint.

Comment: Can I share my Github project with you? May be it will gives you more idea.

Comment: deleteAlertView. awakeFromNib() try this line before deleteAlertView.delegate = self . if this will not work then you can share github project.

Comment: Actually I am struggling with that since last day and today I finally post it. I have tried everything but nothing works. I really appreciate your effort. Here is the link: https://github.com/MasamMahmood/PhotoCollection

Comment: looking into this. I will let you know shortly.

Comment: I have rectified the issue. loadNib wasn't properly work. I change the code with this `let fotoXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FotoDeleteAlert", owner: self,options: nil)`
`let alertView = fotoXib?.first as! FotoDeleteAlert`
            `alertView.delegate = self`
            `self.view.addSubview(alertView). `

Comment: good! I also verify the exact problem. But I updated in the extension to handle this case. any how best of luck.

Comment: Thank you once again. Just related to this If I wanna send `let imgId = AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].projectUnitImageId` to `didDeleteButtonClicked` function any idea how can I do that ? means pass parameter.

Comment: yes you can do that by simply creating a variable inside of FotoDeleteAlert.

Comment: Yes but how to pass from `cellForItemAt` not getting that one. Because `addTarget removeImage` not accept second parameter..

Comment: you just need to add one line inside of cellforitemat <
cell.closeIcon.tag = imgId >
After that you can simply get imgId inside of removeImage by following code.
< let id = sender.tag >

Comment: Yes I am doing same thing but on `sender.tag` I am getting 1 value but actual image value is `40992` which is ImageID and have to use for pass to delete web services.

Comment: So you need a complete object inside of removeImage() function?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am really sorry I am taking too much time.

Comment: You need to create another class for <closeIcon>. if <closeIcon> data type is UIImageView then this class will be inherited from UIImageView. In that calss you can create a variable where you will be able to save complete object.

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
@objc func removeImage(_ sender: AnyObject){
            deleteAlertView?.delegate = self
            let alert = FotoDeleteAlert.loadViewFromNib()
            alert!.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(alert!)
        }
```

you are setting the delegate on an uninitialized alert view (which will be nil at this point). Set the delegate on the created alert:

```
 let alert = FotoDeleteAlert.loadViewFromNib()
 alert!.frame = self.view.bounds
 alert!.delegate = self
 self.view.addSubview(alert!)
```

from your posted code I see no use for storing `deleteAlertView`

Comment: I am trying to use your way but `alert!.delegate = self` is not available. How can I pass value imageID ? I haven't mentioned my delete web service function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialise your AlertView. so first you have to initialise your alert view by frame.

as below:

```
@objc func removeImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        deleteAlertView = FotoDeleteAlert(frame: .zero)
        deleteAlertView?.delegate = self
        let alert = FotoDeleteAlert.loadViewFromNib()
        alert!.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(alert!)
    }
```

then you have your target should assign in `override func awakeFromNib()` see below code:

```
@IBDesignable class FotoDeleteAlert: UIView {

    var delegate: handleDeleteAction?
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteBtn: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutIfNeeded()
        self.deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didDelete(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func didCancel(_ sender: Any) {
        removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func didDelete(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.didDeleteButtonClicked(sender as! UIButton)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution and on `override init`  `deleteBtn`gives me Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: can I share my GitHub sample project with you?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I have rectified the issue and it was xib as it's not loading properly so I changed the code for it.

```
let fotoXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FotoDeleteAlert", owner: self,options: nil) 
let alertView = fotoXib?.first as! FotoDeleteAlert 
alertView.delegate = self 
self.view.addSubview(alertView).
```